# does random number in the real world follow uniform distribution

Tags: random, uniform-distribution

I am confused about the concept of uniform distribution and random number. Does random number follow uniform distribution or does random number not follow any distribution?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about some sort of generator that creates an endless supply of truly random numbers over a given range, then theoretically the numbers provided should have a uniform distribution.

Comment: So, truly random numbers over a given range should and will have a uniform distribution if get enough number. And numbers have uniform distribution are truly random numbers, since numbers in [a, b] would be return in a same probability 1/(b-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, random is just that, random.  There is nothing that guarantees that after 100 random numbers, at least one of them is non-zero.  You'd probably think something is broken, and while you'd probably be right, it *is* just as possible as any other combination of numbers in the same given range.

Uniform distribution will ensure that statistically speaking, your values will be spread out across a given range.  In that case if you got 100 random uniformly distributed numbers and they were all zero, something is definitely broken.

Answer (score 2):

Any number generator guaranteeing a uniform distribution is not random. That said, the more numbers you generate, the more likely it is to resemble a uniform distribution.

Comment: Imagine that I need random number in [60, 220]. There would be 160 number in it. I am going to get truly numbers. So, if I get number less than 160 or just 160 times, numbers would be different with each other and not uniform distribution? If I get number more than 160 times, some number would appear again, and all numbers I get might have uniform distribution or definitely have uniform distribution?

Comment: I think that a random number generator will *resemble* a uniform distribution, I don't think at any point it will actually meet a mathematically rigorous definition for a uniform distribution. I don't think you can pick a "tipping" point where it becomes a uniform distribution.